# How to convert a value in to hour and minute in Excel

Tags: excel

```
FROM    TO  TOTALHOURS  ANSWER
5:00 AM 6:05 AM 1.08          1HOUR 5MINUTS
5:00 AM 6:50 AM 1.83          1 HOUR 50 MINUTES
5:00 AM 2:59 PM 9.98          9 HOURS 59 MINUTES
5:00 AM 6:06 AM 1.10          1 HOUR 6 MINUTES
5:00 AM 6:07 AM 1.12          1 HOUR 17 MINUTES
```

I just want a formula to count exact hour and minutes same like answer column

Answer (score 2):

Subtract two values and use  [Hour](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/hour-function-HA001228852.aspx?CTT=1) and [Minute](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/mac-excel-help/minute-function-HA102927850.aspx?CTT=1) on the result

Assuming Your Data starts from Cell A1..

```
=HOUR(B2-A2)&" Hour " &MINUTE(B2-A2)&" Minutes"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a reference to the cell and then apply a custom format such as `h " HOURS" mm " MINUTES"`

N.B. This won't automatically adjust for plurals

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Thinkingcap 's example, but with proper handling of plurals

```
=HOUR(B2-A2 ) & " hour"  & IF(HOUR(B2-A2)>1 ; "s " ; " ")  & MINUTE(B2-A2 ) & " minute" & IF(MINUTE(B2-A2)>1 ; "s " ; " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

In **D2** enter:

```
=INT(C2)&" HOUR"&IF(INT(C2)=1," ","S ")&ROUND((C2-INT(C2))*60,0)&" MINUTE" & IF(ROUND((C2-INT(C2))*60,0)=1,"","S")
```

and copy down:

[image]